# Foreign Key : Unique & part of Composite Primary Key

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, composite-primary-key, unique-key

I have the  tables:

( `coupon` )

```
| id |    name  |    description   |     start_at       |       end_at        |
| 1  | coupon_1 | FREE coupon ...  |2017-02-01 04:00:33 | 2017-02-15 04:00:33 |
```

( `coupon_code` )

```
| id | coupon_id |    code   |
| 1  |    1      | P69MFE5K  |
| 13 |    1      | 75PRUE4G  |
```

( `coupon_recipient` )

```
| coupon_id | user_id | couponcode_id |
|    1      |    4    |      1        |
|    1      |    4    |      13       |
```

The `coupon_recipient` Keys:

`coupon_id, user_id, couponcode_id` = `Composite Primary Key`

`couponcode_id` = `Unique Index`

Is it ok to have `couponcode_id` as part of `composite primary key` & `unique index`?

Because a `User` can receive the `same coupon` multiple times with different `coupon_code` ( `Composite Primary Key` )

The same `coupon_code` can only be used `1 time` ( `Unique Index` )

Comment: If you need more discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical reason you can't have couponcode_id as the unique index and as part of the primary key.  However, I don't see any practical reason to use coupon_id & user_id in the PK as it just makes the table key wider, which can negatively affect performance.

Assuming your Primary Key is also the clustered index key, if couponcode_id is unique in coupon_recipient, why not just use that as the primary key.  You could than create a Non-clustered index for the coupon_id & user_id.

Comment: (In MySQL, the PK is, by definition, clustered with the data, `UNIQUE`, and an index.)